# Cheat sheet, sublime text 2 for mac 13 inch keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, sublime-text-2

I need full keyboard shortcuts for sublime text2 on macbook retina 13 inch. Searched google but didn't get a full chart that I could print.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a Github gist](https://gist.github.com/lucasfais/1207002) that lists the Mac OS hotkeys for ST2.

You may also want to use [Cheatsheet](http://www.grandtotal.biz/CheatSheet/) (usable not just for ST2, but for other apps as well).